# Padding zeros in a string

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script to get some podcasts.  The problem is that some of the podcast numbers are one digits while others are two/three digits, therefore I need to pad them to make them all 3 digits.

I tried the following:

```
n=1

n = printf %03d $n

wget http://aolradio.podcast.aol.com/sn/SN-$n.mp3
```

but the variable 'n' doesn't stay padded permanently.  How can I make it permanent?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Use command substitution to assign the result of the `printf` command:

```
n=1
wget http://aolradio.podcast.aol.com/sn/SN-$(printf %03d $n).mp3
```

EDIT: Note that I removed one line which was not really necessary.
If you want to assign the output of 'printf %...' to n, you could
use

```
n=$(printf %03d $n)
```

and after that, use the $n variable substitution you used before.

Comment: Why not: `wget $(printf http://aolradio.podcast.aol.com/sn/SN-%03d $n.mp3, $n)`. Just put the whole URL in the `printf` statement.

Comment: What if you actually need to pad a string? for example, I have the string "Hello" but I need to always print 10 characters, I would need to print the string: "-----Hello" or if I have "yes" I still get 10 characters printed as: "-------yes"

Answer (score 50):

Seems you're assigning the return value of the printf command (which is its exit code), you want to assign the output of printf.

```
bash-3.2$ n=1
bash-3.2$ n=$(printf %03d $n)
bash-3.2$ echo $n
001
```

Comment: Why is $() preferable?

Comment: @bli It can be nested, whereas backticks cannot (at least not without some form of escaping)

Answer (score 25):

Attention though if your input string has a leading zero!
printf will still do the padding, but also convert your string to <strike>hex</strike> octal format.

```
# looks ok
$ echo `printf "%05d" 03`
00003

# but not for numbers over 8
$ echo `printf "%05d" 033`
00027
```

A solution to this seems to be printing a float instead of decimal.
The trick is omitting the decimal places with `.0f`.

```
# works with leading zero
$ echo `printf "%05.0f" 033`
00033

# as well as without
$ echo `printf "%05.0f" 33`
00033
```

Comment: That's because printf takes "0n" as octal. octal 33 = decimal 27. Not hex.

Answer (score 22):

to avoid context switching:

```
a="123"
b="00000${a}"
c="${b: -5}"
```

Comment: this! . . . . <3

Comment: inverse: `while [ "${s:0:1}" = '0' ]; do s=${s:1}; done`

Comment: Be aware this will cut off numbers which have more than 5 digits. To avoid that, try `a="123456"; [[ ${#a} -lt 5 ]] && a="00000${a}" && a="${a: -5}"; echo "$a"`

Answer (score 4):

```
n=`printf '%03d' "2"`
```

Note spacing and backticks

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by noselad, please command substitution, i.e. $(...), is preferable as it supercedes backtics, i.e. `` `...` ``.

Much easier to work with when trying to nest several command substitutions instead of escaping, i.e. "backslashing", backtics.

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to an answer given by cC Xx.
It will work only until `a`'s value less is than 5 digits.

Consider when `a=12345678`.
It'll truncate the leading digits:

```
a="12345678" 
b="00000${a}" 
c="${b: -5}" 
echo "$a, $b, $c"
```

This gives the following output:

```
12345678, 0000012345678, 45678
```

Putting an `if` to check value of `a` is less than 5 digits and then doing it could be solution:

```
if [[ $a -lt 9999 ]] ; then b="00000${a}" ; c="${b: -5}" ;  else c=$a; fi
```

Comment: Putting an if to check value of a is less than 5 digits and then doing it could be solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just typing this here for additional information.

If you know the number of zeroes you need, you can use the string concatenation:

```bash
let pad="0"
pad+=1
echo $pad # this will print 01
```