# Ignore possible non-digits on the end of numbers in sed substitutions

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to pad strings with zeros until they reach a limit of four digits, for example:

```
1 -> 0001
44 -> 0044
555 -> 0555
1a -> 0001a
44b -> 0044b
565c -> 0565c
7890 -> 7890
```

I have a bash script and I add the file containing those numbers as a parameter.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
if [ ! -f $FILE ]; then
    exit 1
fi

sed -i 's/\<[0-9]\>/0&/g' $FILE
sed -i 's/\<[0-9][0-9]\>/0&/g' $FILE
sed -i 's/\<[0-9][0-9][0-9]\>/0&/g' $FILE
```

The script is not working on the `1a, 44b, 565c`. I don't know how to ignore the letters.

Comment: `\>` is matching the word boundary: `1a` is considered a single word

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Padding zeros in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117134/padding-zeros-in-a-string)

Comment: I disagree with @funky-future 's dupe flag, that question was about using printf, this is about sed, in both cases the question asker already knows how to do the padding and is having trouble with the implementation

Comment: Can you give a typical input line? Can there be several such numbers per line?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 2):

GNU **awk** would be a better tool here:

```
awk -i inplace 'match($1,/([0-9]*)(.*)/,arr){$1=sprintf("%04d%s",arr[1],arr[2])}1' input.txt
```

which pads $1 to 4 digits.

Testing:

```
$ cat input.txt
1
44
555
1a
44b
565c
7890

awk 'match($1,/([0-9]*)(.*)/,arr){$1=sprintf("%04d%s",arr[1],arr[2])}1' input.txt
0001
0044
0555
0001a
0044b
0565c
7890
```

Suppose data is ordered like in @xhienne's answer, then we loop over the fields:

```
$ cat input.txt
1 44 555 1a 44b 565c 7890 77777

$ cat tst.awk
{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    if (match($i,/([0-9]*)(.*)/,arr))
      $i=sprintf("%04d%s",arr[1],arr[2])
}1

$ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
0001 0044 0555 0001a 0044b 0565c 7890 77777
```

Comment: Not sure there is only one number at the beginning of the line since the poster used the `g` flag for their substitutions.

Comment: What makes this better than xhienne's sed solution?

Comment: xhienne's solution is wrong. It will turn the number 777777 into 7777.

Comment: Let me rephrase. Xhienne's solution handles numbers with more than 4 digits wrong. There's some things that need to be specified by OP, and therefore there's no right or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix each sequence of digits with `000` and then truncate the result to the last four digits:

```
sed -i '
    s/[0-9]\{1,\}/000&/g
    s/0*\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1/g
' "$FILE"
```

Or with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i -r '
    s/[0-9]+/000&/g
    s/0*([0-9]{4})/\1/g
' "$FILE"
```

Example:

```
Sample line : 1 44 555 1a 44b 565c 7890 77777
```

Yields:

```
Sample line : 0001 0044 0555 0001a 0044b 0565c 7890 77777
```

Comment: I'd recommend against including the `-i` option here, despite the fact that it's in the question, as its use differs between sed implementations. A POSIX solution that modifies the original file would not be possible with sed alone. Also, for the sake of simplicity, it might be useful to mention that this can be done without newlines. `sed -e 's/[0-9]/000&/' -e 's/[0-9]*\([0-9]\{4\}\)/\1/g'` for example. But despite that ... nicely done. :)

Comment: This will cut down numbers of more than 4 digits. "7777777" will be transformed to "7777".

Comment: @MarcLambrichs, yes -- none of the OP's sample data is more than 4 digits. Behaviour in cases with >4 digits are unspecified in the question.

Comment: @ghoti Thanks. The newlines were intentionally added for the sake of readability.

Comment: @ghoti Yup. Just like the number of columns in the input is unspecified.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs There are probably no number exceeding 4 digits, but answer corrected anyway. As for the number of columns, the 'g' substitution flag indicates there may be more than one, and there is no anchor that may indicate that the number is at the first column

Answer (score 0):

To match zero or more characters we can use `*` and to match any non-digit we can use `[^0-9]`

So adapting your regex to include `[^0-9]*` after the digit matches and before the pattern matching the rest of the string should allow matching those letters.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try one more approach with awk and let me know if tis helps you.

```
awk '{val=$0;gsub(/[0-9]+/,"",val);printf("%04d%s\n",$0,val)}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
0001
0044
0555
0001a
0044b
0565c
7890
```

**Explanation:** Adding non-one liner form of solution with explanation too here.

```
awk '{
val=$0;                   ##Storing current line into a variable named val here.
gsub(/[0-9]+/,"",val);    ##Globally substituting all digits with NULL in variable val now, to make sure we are getting everything apart from digits.
printf("%04d%s\n",$0,val);##Now using printf of awk, whose quality is it will automatically take till all digits and do padding with zeros if needed till to make it 4 digit number that is why %04d is being used then I am using %s to print string with respect to the value of val, where we stored all values of strings previously.
}
' Input_file             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```